# Splitting Pandas dataframe on string properties index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to split a dataset into 2 types of datapoints. Currently I have a pandas dataframe with this format.

```
CS1001    True    value1
CM1001    False   value2
CS1002    True    value3
```

Now i would like to split this into a S and a M dataframe like this:

S frame:

```
C1001    True    value1
C1002    True    value3
```

M frame:

```
C1001    False   value2
```

Now i run into two problems fistly I can't seem to group on the first 4 characters with this.

```
data.groupby(data.index[:4])
```

And then I can't edit the index value to remove the S/M. I have not used pandas before so I feel like I'm overseeing an obvious solution but I can't figure it out.

Comment: can you please share code you tried and what issue you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [15]: data
Out[15]:
            1       2
CS1001   True  value1
CM1001  False  value2
CS1002   True  value3

In [16]: data.groupby(data.index.str[:2]).groups
Out[16]:
{'CM': Index(['CM1001'], dtype='object'),
 'CS': Index(['CS1001', 'CS1002'], dtype='object')}
```

Removing second letter from index values:

```
In [5]: df.index = df.index.str[:1] + df.index.str[2:]

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
           1       2
C1001   True  value1
C1001  False  value2
C1002   True  value3
```

Comment: That worked, makes sense that you have to ask for a string with .str. thanks a lot for your help. Would you happen to know how you can edit the value of the index to remove the S/M?

Comment: @FlorianEn, you are welcome. How do you want to convert it: `CS1001` to `C1001` or to `1001`?

Comment: CS1001 to C1001

Comment: Thank you, you've been a huge help

Comment: @FlorianEn, glad i could help :)